# In SQL Alchemy with multiple databases, how to log the db connection creation info at any point in the application?

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy

I am new to SQL alchemy. Can anyone please help me with this

In SQL Alchemy with multiple databases, how to log the db connection creation info ( active connections) at any point in the application ? 
In case of multiple databases, we use the **bind_key** in the model class to specify the schema name for that specific table.

f**rom flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy**
we call SQLAlchemy() , which refers the SQLALCHEMY_BINDS = { } values .

@FranckGamess

**Model class 1**

from model import db

class Pqr_W( db.Model):

```
__bind_key__ = 'dbpqr’
```

**tablename** = ‘table_name_pqr’

**Properties file entry ( settings.py)**

SQLALCHEMY_BINDS = {

```
'dbxyz': 'mysql://root@localhost/xyz_portal',

'dbpqr’: ‘oracle+cx_oracle://root@localhost/xyz_portal',
```

}

**Model class 2**

from model import db

class Xyz_W( db.Model):

```
__bind_key__ = 'dbxyzr’

__tablename__ = ‘table_name_xyz’
```

**Model.py**

from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com, please show us some code, what you have already done ...etc.

Comment: Your question is unclear. You want to log the connections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure what you want to do, you can use `SQLALCHEMY_ECHO = True` which can log all the statements issued to stderr which can be useful for debugging.
FYI :http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/config/